# java: convert calendare string to formated date

Tags: java

please, i have a problem in my code, i have a method that gives me a calendar but it's a string:

```
lastModif = sftpChannel.lstat(remoteFile).getMtimeString();
```

the output is String :

example:

```
System.out.println(lastModif); || output is ==>  Tue Oct 14 12:48:15 WEST 2014
```

I want to format this string to have just this outpu : 2014-10-14.

I don't know how can i convert this String  "Oct 14 12:48:15 WEST 2014" to date.

and after this conversion i will compare two date.

Thank you

Comment: I don't either. What timezone is WEST?

Comment: SimpleDateFormat http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: @ElliottFrisch:  [West European Summer Time](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/eu/west.html)

Comment: @mond14 What *exactly* is the data type of `lastModif`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Comment: According to the Javadoc, [`getMtimeString()`](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/SftpATTRS.html#getMtimeString()) returns a String representation of the modification time, and [`getMTime()`](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/SftpATTRS.html#getMTime()) returns the number of seconds since January 1, 1970, as an `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a couple of [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)s - one to parse the string you got, and one to reformat it:

```
String lastModif = sftpChannel.lstat(remoteFile).getMtimeString();
DateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

System.out.println(formatter.format(parser.parse(lastModif)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");      
Date date = new Date();     // Or any other date.

System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

And the output will be `2014-10-14`

Answer (score 0):

According to the Javadoc, [`getMtimeString()`](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/SftpATTRS.html#getMtimeString()) returns a String representation of the modification time, and [`getMTime()`](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/SftpATTRS.html#getMTime()) returns the number of seconds since January 1, 1970 (the epoch), as an `int`.

Java typically takes a date as either some string to be parsed, or a `long` number of milliseconds since the epoch, or, in the case of [`java.time.LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), it can take the number of days since the epoch.

Since `getMTime()` returns the number of seconds since the epoch, and there are 86400 seconds in a day, you can simply use it instead of `getMtimeString()` and create a `LocalDate` from it:

```
import static java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE;

import java.time.LocalDate;

public class DaysToDate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ... whatever you need to do to get sftpChannel ...
        int lastModif = sftpChannel.lstat(remoteFile).getMTime();
        long days = lastModif / 86400L;
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.ofEpochDay(days);

        System.out.println(date.format(ISO_LOCAL_DATE));
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

I have used a [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to format the date (there is a predefined formatter for the format you specified named `ISO_LOCAL_TIME`), but that is the same as the default format for `LocalDate`, so you can just call its `toString()` method. If you want to format it differently, just create a `DateTimeFormatter` with the desired format.

Note: Since `getMTime()` represents the number of seconds since January 1, 1970 as a 32-bit `int`, it suffers from the [2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).